# querying a view in oracle using java code with a where condition on a date field

Tags: java, date, jdbc, oracle11g

I need to connect to a view in oracle view which contains information about certain matrix population in other tables.
The structure of the view (v_matrix) is:
PERIOD_START_TIME NOT NULL DATE,
MATRIX_TABLE VARCHAR2(20),
MATRIX_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
COMPLETION_TIME DATE

I am using a java code using jdbc to connect to the view.

The query which i Have is:

```
String query = "Select * from v_matrix where PERIOD_START_TIME LIKE \'2016-04-18 17:%\' AND MATRIX_TABLE = \'" + tableName + "\'  AND MATRIX_NAME IN (" + inClauseStr.toString() + ")";
```

The problem is that the query fetches nothing while I can see around 200 records in the view with PERIOD_START_TIME in order of 17th hour on 18th April 2016.
The same query works fine in SQL Developer

I tried googling bud could not find any tutorial on how to filter records on a date field using java code.

I tried changing the query to

```
String query = "Select * from v_kpi_availability where TO_CHAR(PERIOD_START_TIME,\'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS\') LIKE \'2016-04-18 17:%\' AND KPI_TABLE = \'" + tableName + "\'  AND KPI_NAME IN (" + inClauseStr.toString() + ")";
```

But the query still does not fetch any records
PS: The database is Oracle 11g (11.2.0.4)

Answer (score 0):

Surprising the code works in pre-prod environment  with the following query:

```
String query = "Select * from v_kpi_availability where TO_CHAR(PERIOD_START_TIME,\'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS\') LIKE \'2016-04-18 17:%\' AND KPI_TABLE = \'" + tableName + "\'  AND KPI_NAME IN (" + inClauseStr.toString() + ")";
```

The reason its not working in lab because lab is on Oracle 10g where the implementation of date is a bit different.